# Left Content Bar/Area

Tags: macros, positioning, margins

[image]I am working on a template for papers and documentation. Sometimes, the authors have "key facts" or other items they wish to callout in a left content bar (xxxx is left bar, ccc is main content):

```
 -------------
|xxx   ccccccc|
|xxx   ccccccc|
|xxx   ccccccc|
|xxx   ccccccc|
|xxx   ccccccc|
|xxx   ccccccc|
 -------------
```

Not every page has this sidebar, and those that do not, should have the main text cover the entire page.

My initial idea was to do this with a new command/macro which creates a table or hbox or vbox which lives on the left side of the page.  However, if on one page, the author calls that section twice (e.g. "Key Features" and "Key Benefits") they should both go into the same box since they are on the same page.

How would I do this?

[bonus points if you can also suggest a way to allow overflow to continue on the next page]

[EDIT] I added a picture - what i want to achive is that gray bar on the left side

Comment: if you want the main `cccc` text to automatically flow on to the next page which might be full width then this is very (almost impossibly) difficult to do in TeX.

Comment: @davidCarlisle, so there is no easy way to allow the author to add "multiple" sections to the left bar?

Comment: the left bar is easier, but the hard part is that  tex needs to know the width for linebreaking before the paragraph starts, so you can't (easily) have an automatic page break with narrow lines before the break and wide lines after.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ok - so if we drop the left bar spill over requirement, how could i have someone do \leftBarAddSection{title}{content}  two times on the same page, and have them go to the same left bar?

Comment: as i say  it's the main text `cccc` breaking that is hard, if the ccc was always the same width you could for example just use `\marginpar` to add things to the margin. The hard part is making the `ccc` wider on pages which have no sidebar.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, i was thinking about creating a table or hbox (some other floatbale object) and putting content in there... but is there a way to continuously appending content within one hbox or table via command?

Comment: Yes sure, or you could use \marginpar,

Comment: Quite apart from what @DavidCarlisle says about the difficulty, IMHO it would be very inconsistent and extremely poor style to have a "notes" margin like this which only appears on some pages. The way to solve this is to use a wide margin (geometry package) and a good marginal notes macro. If you insist on having two page styles (one with and one without the margin) it's possible with the \newgeometry setting, but you would then need manual editorial intervention on every page to decide which page layout was to be used.

Answer (score 1):

The `framed` package can do that, if I understand well what  you want. Here is a way  to customise this `leftbar` environment, that can break across pages:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
    \colorlet{TFFrameColor}{IndianRed3}
    \renewenvironment{leftbar}{%
    \def\FrameCommand{{\color{TFFrameColor}\vrule width 2pt} \hspace{3pt}}%
    \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}%
    {\endMakeFramed}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

    \begin{leftbar}
\lipsum[4-6]\
    \end{leftbar}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: can i put text IN the red area? the xxx is content that is in a bar or frame separate from the main content the ccc

Comment: I do not really get what you require. What is IN?

Comment: I updated my post with a picture... by IN i mean, inside the side bar - the gray area. (though this is only happens when someone puts content into the bar, otherwise the page is full width

Comment: The code from `framed` is not done for that. I would try with the `tcolorbox` package, which allows breakable boxes. I don't have time at the moment, but I'll try tomorrow if no one has given an answer.